# Is it possible to install a game with a different CD than the one used to play?

Tags: xbox-360

My CD of AC3 is now scratched beyond repair. I am curious however if it is possible to borrow my friends copy -> install only harddisk -> and play using my CD, assuming that my CD isnt that badly scratched.

Basically I am asking if the installed copy needs to be from the same CD as the one being used to play the game after installing.

Comment: Games don't have that sort of copy protection.  To the console, an AC3 disk is an AC3 disk.  Where you install it from matters not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is nothing that uniquely identifies an Xbox 360 disc. When you start a game that is installed to the hard drive, the console just checks the disc in the drive to verify that it matches the game you're starting.

So long as your disc isn't so damaged that this initial check can't be performed, you should be able to install the game from your friend's disc and play using yours.